# Should I install tools inside WSL 2 or on Windows?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have searched alot on Google, but cannot seem to find any guidelines or definitive answers.
The closest I got was an article stating that I should generate my ssh keys from within WSL and use that ssh key on Windows aswell, which makes sense.

But what about other tools?

I.e. `yarn`, `flutter`, `nodejs/npm`, `.net` etc?

I found that installing `yarn` from chocolatey, also allowed me to use `yarn` within my WSL Ubuntu shell.
However, the same was not true for nodejs nor flutter.

For flutter specifically I found this open issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41742

But perhaps someone can shed some light on what the "best practice" are for installing tools/software using WSL?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034404/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-using-shared-node-js-installation-with-windows