# In WSL2: Ubuntu 20.04 for Windows 10 nodejs is installed but npm is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I am using **WSL2: Ubuntu 20.04** in my **Windows 10** operating system. I have installed `nodejs` using the command `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` when I do `node -v` command I get `v12.18.3`

```
mrd@DESKTOP-2EO5K4H:/mnt/c/Users/musfi$ node -v
v12.18.3
```

but when I do `npm -v` command I get this below command

```
mrd@DESKTOP-2EO5K4H:/mnt/c/Users/musfi$ npm -v
-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I also do `whereis` command. Hope this will help to find solution.

```
mrd@DESKTOP-2EO5K4H:/mnt/c/Users/musfi$ whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/include/node /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz

mrd@DESKTOP-2EO5K4H:/mnt/c/Users/musfi$ whereis npm
npm: /usr/bin/npm /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm.cmd /usr/share/man/man1/npm.1
```

I have tried almost all the stackoverflow solutions and github issues but nothing is worked for me.
Hope any kind soul has the solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try this

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
sudo apt install npm
```

Comment: It has worked. Can you explain to me which PATH you export? And what was the problem?

Comment: PATH is env variable which tells where to look for commands,in your case the npm bin was not at the right path.

Comment: The ONLY thing that worked across the entire internet, including Chat GPT. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it is still helping people.

Answer (score 17):

A better way is configuring `/etc/wsl.conf` in your Windows User directory.

Adding this into the `/etc/wsl.conf`, so Windows Path will not take the precedence

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath=false
```

For more config details check the Microsoft Dev Blog [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/).

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. If node/npm is installed in both WSL2 and your Windows host OS, this will cause issues due to path interoperability.

Comment: This worked.

For anyone else, the issue I had was:



`/mnt/c/Windows/system32/nvm: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token ('`
`/mnt/c/Windows/system32/nvm: line 1: Downloading node.js version 14.19.3 (32-bit)... '`

Answer (score 8):

Solution for following error:
`-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Edit `~/.bashrc`
Append at end of file:

```sh
# strip out problematic Windows %PATH%
PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:\/mnt.*//g')
```

Now `npm init` will work.

Answer (score 7):

To install `nodejs` in WSL don't use `apt` follow Microsoft's guidance:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

See also how to remove `nodejs` if you installed it via `apt`:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/786015/how-to-remove-nodejs-from-ubuntu-16-04

For `npm` to work under **WSL1**:

- You may also need to disable `ipv6` (or [configure to prefer `ipv4`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200257/368145)) - if you are [hitting these issues](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3359).
- Under WSL1 [I disabled `ipv6` on my **main NIC**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1013248/368145) & `npm install` immediately began working.

---

**WSL2 Notes**:

**NB: if you use a VPN your container connectivity ***may*** be broken under WSL2** (e.g [with Cisco AnyConnect](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4277)) - the fix works but may no longer be needed under AnyConnect (WSL2 on a VPN now works for me after a recent update @ end of July 2022)

I thought my WSL containers were running under WSL2 (I upgraded the WSL kernel with `wsl --update`) - while setting up Visual Studio with WSL I saw a WSL1 warning. You also have to upgrade containers:

```
wsl --set-version ubuntu-22.04 2
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

To get Visual Studio integration working properly with Ubuntu `22.04` in WSL you also currently have to upgrade `gzip` to install `VS Code Server for x64` in WSL (`code .:` in the Linux terminal):

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gzip/gzip_1.12-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./gzip_1.12-1_amd64.deb
```

Finally I upgraded `npm` & everything works (choose one of the following commands):

- `nvm install-latest-npm`
- `npm install -g npm@latest`

**Azure AD / CLI Notes**

If you use `nodejs` with Azure Active Directory there seems to be an issue with the `azure-cli` forgetting credentials under WSL1 / WSL2 & persistently telling you to `az login`. In this case you need to run your `local` node development instances on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For all Unix/Linux/MacOS operating systems, I would always rather go with the "Node Version Manager". It normally works flawlessly on Linux and MacOS (and there's a Windows port for it as well) and enables a very simple way of installing `node` and `npm` correctly without the need of being `root`.

See here: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

I can confirm here on my machine that it also works on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2.

Comment: `nvm` (and `n`) are anti-patterns