# NPM Not initiating

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-request

I installed the node.js from `node.js.org`. It is my understanding that NPM downloads automatically with node. I went through the steps and the node was installed successfully as shown in PDF I attached.

When I go into hyper to initialize npm, I get a message saying

> zsh: command not found: npm

I am currently using the later version of MAC (12/2019).  I am not sure if NPM is in my path or `enter code here how to get it in the path.  Can someone please assist me?

[[image]]

Comment: What happens when you enter  'npm  -v' into your terminal?

Comment: check `echo $PATH` whether your path is correct or not according to image, if not follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63716693/13126651

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: Hi Jatin, how do I know if my PATH is correct?  This is all new to me and I so confused and trying to sort things out.  Please be patient with me.  When I enter echo $PATH,  I get this return: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin.

Comment: Hi Ajay,  when I enter npm -v  I get this return: v14.16.0. When I enter npm init.  I get this return: zsh: command not found: npm