# WSL can't detect VS code

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

At first, I tried to fix my problem of npm instruction

so I added

```
[interop] 
appendWindowsPath = false
```

to /etc/wsl.conf

It works, but another problem happen.

When I type `code .`

```
Command 'code' not found, did you mean:
  command 'node' from deb nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3)
  command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
  command 'ode' from deb plotutils (2.6-11)
  command 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-11ubuntu1)
  command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.2)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

The above Error message appear.

I tried the following instruction

```
export PATH=$PATH:"/mnt/c/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin"
```

It also works properly.

Whenever I restarted WSL, npm instruction still worked well, but code instruction lost its function again.

What should I do to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My main suggestion would be to not use `appendWindowsPath = false` to fix your NPM problem.  That's like using a sledgehammer as a flyswatter.  As I said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70793637/11810933):

> Please do *not* follow the recommendations (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63716693/11810933)) to completely remove all Windows paths from WSL, as that will severely limit your ability to run Windows applications in WSL (one of its great features).

You'll also lose access to the ability to run PowerShell scripts and commands in WSL easily.  You won't have direct access to `wsl.exe` itself from inside WSL (which comes in handy).

You can type the full paths to these commands, of course, but most instructions and other answers you find here are going to assume that you've left the Windows path intact.

Instead, figure out where `npm` is installed in your WSL distribution and then determine why it is further toward the end of the `PATH` than your Windows directories.  Windows paths are added *at the end* of the Linux `PATH` for a reason.  If something in your startup files is adding to the path, it should put it at the beginning, so it has precedence.  E.g.:

```
export PATH="newdir:$PATH"
```

Note that I'm not saying that you should change your `export` statement above since, as mentioned, that Windows path would normally come at the end anyway.  It's really not going to matter unless you put another `code` executable somewhere else in your path.

> Whenever I restarted WSL, npm instruction still worked well, but code instruction lost its function again.

If you do want the "quick and dirty" (not recommended) solution, then you can simply add that `export` command that "makes it work" to your `~/.bashrc`.  That file is processed each time the Bash shell starts interactively.